# MySQL query run time is better even though its execution plan is bad

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize this MySQL query and having less experience in understanding execution plan I am having hard time making sense of the execution plan.

**My question is :** Can you please help me in understanding why the query execution plan of **New Query** is worse than that of **Original query** even though New query performs better in Prod.

SQL needed to reproduce this case is [here](https://pastebin.com/xM0w7ARp)
Also kept relevant table definition in the end ( Table bill_range references bill using foreign key bill_id )

**Original query** takes 10 second to complete in PROD

```
select * 
from bill_range 
where (4050 between low and high ) 
order by bill_id limit 1;
```

while **new query** (I am forcing/suggesting to use index) takes 5 second to complete in PROD

```
select * 
from bill_range 
use index ( bill_range_low_high_index) 
where (4050 between low and high ) 
order by bill_id limit 1;
```

But the execution plan gives suggest original query is better( this is the part where my understanding seems to be wrong )

**Original query**
[image]

**New query**
[image]

1. Column "type" for  original query suggest *index* while new query
   says *ALL*
2. Column "Key" is *bill_id* (perhaps index on FK) for
   original queryand *Null* for new query
3. Column "rows" for  original query is *1* while for new query says *9*

So given all this information wouldn't it imply that new query is actually worse than original query .
And if that is true why is new query performing better? Or am I reading the execution plan wrong.

**Table defintions**

```
CREATE TABLE bill_range (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    low varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    high varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    bill_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (bill_id) REFERENCES bill(id)
);
CREATE TABLE bill (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    label varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
create index bill_range_low_high_index on bill_range( low, high);
```

NOTE : The reason I am providing definition  of  2 tables is because original query decided to use an index based on Foreign key  to bill table

Comment: What is the cardinality of the index? If it has poor cardinality, using the index doesn't help.

Comment: The query doesn't use the `bill` table, why do we need its definition?

Comment: The optimizer doesn't always get it right, and your benchmark may not be reproducible.  For instance, when you benchmarked the first query at 10 seconds, there could have been other processes running on MySQL at that time.  Generally, you want to avoid forcing the use of an index, as MySQL is smarter than you (most of the time).

Comment: @Barmar in PROD the bill_range_low_high_index has  cardinality of 200K

Comment: Wait a second, what's the problem? Forcing it to use the index improved performance. Why are you questioning that?

Comment: @Barmar so I want to fix my understanding in reading execution plans. If I will read the execution plan of new query , I think it is worse than original query , right ? and just based on the execution plan I wouldnt have been able to conclude that new query is better.

Comment: I agree it's confusing.

Comment: @Barmar just to add so the question boils down to : how come a query with bad  execution plan is performing better . Why type=ALL and key=NULL in new query  has no negative impact

Comment: NO NO!  Don't compare a number (`4500`) with a `VARCHAR`!!  Fix that, then recheck everything discussed here; it may no longer be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Your index isn't quite optimal for your query. Let me explain if I may.

MySQL indexes use BTREE data structures. Those work well in indexed-sequential access mode (hence the MyISAM name of MySQL's first storage engine). It favors queries that jump to a particular place in an index and then run through the index element by element. The typical example is this, with an index on `col`.

```
 SELECT whatever FROM tbl WHERE col >= constant AND col <= constant2
```

That is a rewrite of `WHERE col BETWEEN constant AND constant2`.

Let's recast your query so this pattern is obvious, and so the columns you want are explicit.

```sql
select id, low, high, bill_id 
from bill_range 
where low <= 4050 
  and high >= 4050 
order by bill_id limit 1;
```

An index on the `high` column allows a range scan starting with the first eligible row with `high >= 4050`. Then, we can go on to make it a compound index, including the `bill_id` and `low` columns.

```sql
CREATE INDEX high_billid_low ON bill_range (high, bill_id, low);
```

Because we want the lowest matching `bill_id` we put that into the index next, then finally the `low` value. So the query planner random accesses the index to the first elibible row by `high`, then scans until it finds the very first index item that meets the `low` criterion. And then it's done: that's the desired result. It's already ordered by `bill_id` so it can stop. `ORDER BY` comes from the index. The query can be satisfied entirely from the index -- it is a so-called *covering index*.

As to **why your two queries performed differently**: In the first, the query planner decided to scan your data in `bill_id` order looking for the first matching `low`/`high` pair. Possibly it decided that actually sorting a result set would likely be more expensive than scanning `bill_id`s in order. It looks to me like your second query did a table scan. Why that was faster, who knows?

Notice that this index would also work for you.

```sql
CREATE INDEX low_billid_high ON bill_range (low DESCENDING, bill_id, high);
```

In InnoDB the table's PK `id` is implicitly part of every index, so there's no need to mention it in the compound index.

And, you can still write it the way you first wrote it; the query planner will figure out what you want.

**Pro tip**: Avoid `SELECT *` ... the `*` makes it harder to reason about the columns you need to retrieve.

Comment: I think that that 'rewrite' is exactly what the parser is doing.  Do `EXPLAIN ...; SHOW WARNINGS;` to verify.

Comment: A note on indexes:  `INDEX(x DESC, y ASC)` honors the `DESC` in MySQL 8.0.  It is ignored in all other versions.  This note is important _only_ if you are doing `ORDER BY x DESC, y ASC` and `ORDER BY x ASC, y DESC`.  I can't imagine that it matters in `WHERE`.

Comment: Comments/ Answer taught a lot. Few notable points: (1) columns `low` and `high` are of type varchar (as in my PROD). (2)`SHOW WARNINGS` got `cannot use range access on index 'bill_range_low_high_index' due to type or collation conversion on field 'low'   `. (3) This goes away if I use `int`  for `low` , `high` and execution plan of NEW QUERY improves but ORIGINAL QUERY execution plan still is better.  (4) TODO: I wasn't able to test run time in my actual project if I change to `int`. Will update the result. (5) Indexes proposed in the  solution didn't change the execution plan